# Preparing for Set Theory Research

Tags: set-theory, soft-question, career, advice

Is reading Jech's text on [Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540440852) too little, just enough, or overkill to prepare oneself to do independent research in set theory?  This would be my first attempt at doing independent research after taking 5 graduate level math courses and doing well.  If I think I'm interested in Set Theory, and want to get a feel for research, is this the way to proceed?

Comment: The best way to get ready for research is to read other people's research papers in the subfield where you'd like to do your work.

Comment: The best (only?) way to prepare oneself for research is to to enroll in a graduate program and follow the advice of your advisor.  In any case, this question is off-topic for MO and I have voted to close.

Comment: It sounds likely that OP hasn't yet approached a potential thesis advisor (or hasn't yet been accepted as a student of such), in fact might be an undergraduate, and just wants an idea if Jech will bring up him/her to speed with cutting-edge problems. I think that's more or less a reasonable thing to ask.

Comment: @ToddTrimble : Do you really think that this is a reasonable question for MO?

Comment: Some universities don't have anyone good who works in set theory and related areas, so the situation may be more complicated than simply asking an advisor even if the OP is a graduate student.

Comment: @AndyPutnam: yes, but I don't plan on arguing the point with anyone (you in particular). I'll concede that your point makes some sense to me; it's a judgment call IMO.

Comment: I don't think the question is appropriate for MO, but anyway: No, of course Jech's book is not enough. Jech's text is just introductory. An excellent introduction, for sure, but an introduction nonetheless.

Comment: While I'm ambivalent about the question, I think @AndyPutman's 1st comment is a bit sweeping. Initial guidance is important, but so is independent curiosity/initiative.

Comment: I stand by the substance of my comment, but I apologize for its tone.  In any case, I really don't think this is an appropriate question for MO.

Comment: I've never heard of anyone being hurt by reading too much, too fast, but I wouldn't be shocked if the surgeon general required a label warning against that on the back of Jech's Set Theory...

Comment: Andy, could you explain why not? Perhaps it should be CW? I think that it is a question that could easily be asked by a graduate student at math tea, and it can only be sensibly answered by someone with lots of familiarity with the text and with what it takes to undertake research in set theory.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : Well, first it strikes me as extremely naive.  The obvious answer is "no" -- there is no branch of mathematics in which the reading of a single book is sufficient to prepare you for independent research.  And I think that questions like "what do I need to read to do research in subject X" (which is broader than the question here) are too unfocused.

Comment: Well, an answer of "no" could be a fine answer as well! But I don't think it's entirely clear cut, just on general principle. One can imagine a very clever undergraduate reading, say, Diestel's Graph Theory, and then solving thesis-worthy problems in graph theory through some general knowledge of what has been done and by dint of sheer cleverness -- this type of thing does happen. In other words, I think it really depends on the type of mathematics -- and this is where informed professionals such as Joel can provide valuable and nuanced advice.

Comment: There's a false premise behind the question, which is that the way to prepare to do research is to read a book. Reading is part of it, but what you really need is to develop a feeling for what problems are (1) unsolved, (2) important, and (3) tractable. It's very hard to develop this feeling on your own (though a few exceptional people can do it). Reading a book is certainly not sufficient. Conversely, it is not necessary either; for any particular problem you end up solving, much of Jech will probably be irrelevant. That said, if you don't have an advisor right now, reading Jech can't hurt.

Comment: [Meta](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/224/6085).

Answer (score 12):

I believe that Jech's book is a solid part of any graduate student's preparation for independent research in set theory. He covers most or even all of the main topics of set-theoretic research, and he does so at quite a high level, including some extremely advanced material. For further study of large cardinals, however, the book should probably be supplemented by Kanamori's book The Higher Infinite (see [my review](http://jdh.hamkins.org/bookreviewkanamori/)), and for learning forcing, I always encourage my graduate students to read both Jech and also Kunen's book, as well as some others, especially Bell's book on forcing via Boolean-valued models (and [my own article on the Boolean ultrapower](http://jdh.hamkins.org/boolean-ultrapowers/)), and to play all these texts off of one another, as each has some strengths the others lack.

Jech's book is extremely thorough, and I suppose that if you mastered every last bit of it, then indeed I think it would position you for independent research in set theory. But of course, the more typical pattern is to read at first only the easier parts of it, while also learning from other books, and gradually bring oneself to the research level that way.

During and after your study of Jech, you will need someone to guide you to research topics and problems, to suggest problems or areas that might be fruitful for your independent work or which may interest you.

Comment: But Joel, Jech's is only thorough on introductory material, don't you think? If one wants to learn forcing axioms, or pcf theory, or determinacy, or reflection principles, or just about any current topic, Jech's book only provides a cursory presentation.

Comment: I agree with Andres, and in particular the proof of the covering lemma on chapter 18 is presented in a way where there is some "minor bits left for the reader", but that's actually the main difficulty of the proof and I felt cheated when I saw the whole proof in class some two years ago and compared it to the proof in Jech.

Comment: Yes, it is an introductory graduate text. But meanwhile, I don't know of any introductory course that covers *all* of Jech. I think to cover it in its entireity would fill three or four semesters at least (but I wouldn't recommend this, since one would want to see more large cardinals and other topics, as you mention, and use other books for that). He does cover quite a bit of forcing axioms (e.g. MA, MM, PFA, etc.) and even some pcf theory and determinacy. He is much less thorough on large cardinals, which is why I find Jech+Kanamori a great combination.

Comment: On forcing axioms: The proof of the consistency of $\mathsf{MM}$ leaves out all the difficulties. In fact, the treatment of iterations is much less thorough than in his "Multiple forcing" book. (And in terms of the *theory* of forcing axioms, the results there are badly outdated.) In the 70s, when it first appeared, Jech's book would have been enough to leave you ready for research. Nowadays, it is impossible to achieve that with a book. Anyway, if we want something that after Jech brings us closer, then the Handbook is the place to go.

Comment: Andres, I would add that you and I probably don't agree 100% on what counts as a "current" topic in set theory, since I find it likely that I may be more of a generalist than you, and to be a generalist takes a different kind of preparation.

Comment: If you say so, Joel.

Comment: Andres, are you arguing with my main statement, "Jech's book is a solid part of any graduate student's preparation for independent research in set theory"? Or perhaps you are arguing only with my reluctant admission that if someone mastered every last bit of Jech's book (which never happens), then one would be prepared for research in set theory. If the latter, then I basically agree, which I why my students are also reading Kanamori, etc. as well as research articles, and so on.

Comment: Of course I agree with the main statement. I disagree that knowing the book thoroughly would allow you to do research nowadays (but I accept there may be exceptions). I agree that Kanamori's book and others would also be essential. Still, I don't think that books are the way to reach the appropriate place. (I also don't know what being a generalist is, but I suspect that is something that would be more interesting to chat about over dinner or a beer.)

Comment: So it seems that probably we are in basic agreement. And yes, let's discuss it further over drinks!

Comment: (I have a plan. Maybe in a year. I'll let you know.)

Comment: I'm intrigued...

Comment: My own path to set theory involved reading through the green version of Jech's book back in the late 80s.  No one at my undergrad did set theory, but I ran across Jech's book in the library and I was hooked.

Comment: Of course, things that took me weeks to figure out on my own were clarified in a few minutes of discussion with Andreas once I got into grad school...